# QMake: how to choose version of library to link to

Tags: qt, opencv, computer-vision, cross-compiling, qmake

There is simple computer vision application that uses OpenCV. I am compiling it on host system than deploy to NVidia Jetson TK1 (no problems here, I use Qt Creator with configured kit). I use `sshfs` to mount Jetson's filesystem root to host `/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1`.

The problem: I've just compiled OpenCV version 3.2 on Jetson (installed into board `/usr/local/lib`). There are still system OpenCV version 2.4 in `/usr/local`. I don't know how to configure qmake on host system to cross compile and link new version instead of a Jetson's system default.

My .pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = markerExtractionChromakey
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

unix: INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
unix: QMAKE_LIBDIR = /usr/local/lib

unix: LIBS +=  -lopencv_imgproc\
               -lopencv_core.so\
               -lopencv_video\
               -lopencv_highgui\
               -lopencv_gpu

TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += cameraworker.h

SOURCES += main.cpp \
           cameraworker.cpp

target.path = /home/ubuntu/alan/markerExtractionChromakey
target.files += markerExtractionChromakey
INSTALLS += target
```

Project linkage output:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1/usr/lib
-Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
-Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -mfloat-abi=hard
 --sysroot=/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qt5/lib
-o markerExtractionChromakey main.o cameraworker.o   -L/usr/local/lib
-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui 
-lopencv_gpu -L/opt/qt5_for_tegra/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/lib 
-lQt5Core -L/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1/usr/lib 
-L/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
-L/mnt/sysroot_tegra_tk1/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lpthread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The key moments:

1. Different versions placed in different locations (using explicit soname is an option, but in my case libraries placed outside linker default scope).
2. There must be correct `-rpath/-rpath-link` to tell linker where to look for.
3. Default `-rpath` locations for Jetson specified in `<path to Qt>/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-jetson-tk1-g++/qmake.conf`. Just add your directory before the default ones:

   ```
   QMAKE_INCDIR += \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/local/include \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf

   QMAKE_LIBDIR += \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/local/lib \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
       $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf

   QMAKE_LFLAGS += \
       -Wl,-rpath-link,$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/local/lib \
       -Wl,-rpath-link,$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib \
       -Wl,-rpath-link,$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
       -Wl,-rpath-link,$$[QT_SYSROOT]/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
   ```